# How Can I manage my java applet using panels?

Tags: java

I wrote a little Weekly Pay Applet using java. But when it comes to getting a decent layout I'm clueless. I started to add the panel and grid layout into the code. But I don't know how to implement them.

Here's the code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WeeklyPayCalculatorApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener {

   //define variables, Button, label, TextField
      //Create a Button class




      Label title1 = new Label("Western Distribution");
      Label title2 = new Label("Weekly Payroll Calculation");
      Label lblEnterMins = new Label("Enter Total Minutes Worked: ");
      Label lblEnterHours = new Label("Enter Hourly Pay Rate: ");
      Label lblHoursWorked = new Label("Hours Worked:");
      Label lblLeftOver = new Label("Leftover Miutes:");
      Label lblWeekPay = new Label("Weekly Pay:");

      Label hoursWorked = new Label("  ");
      Label leftoverMins = new Label("  ");
      Label weeklyPay = new Label("  ");

      TextField txtMinutes = new TextField(10);
      TextField txtRate = new TextField(10);


   Button btnPay = new Button("Weekly Pay");
   Button btnClear = new Button("Clear");
   Button btnExit=new Button("Exit");


    //Panels

    Panel pnlCenter = new Panel();
    Panel pnlSouth = new Panel();
    Panel pnlNorth = new Panel();

        //Grids
    GridLayout gridLay1 = new GridLayout(1,3);


      public void init() {
      // add the displayable objects;
      add("Center", pnlCenter);
      pnlCenter.setLayout(gridLay1);
        pnlCenter.add(title1);
        pnlCenter.add(title2);
        add(lblEnterMins);
        add(txtMinutes);
        add(lblEnterHours);
        add(txtRate);

        add(btnPay);
        add(btnClear);
        add(btnExit);

        add(lblHoursWorked);
        add(hoursWorked);
        add(lblLeftOver);
        add(leftoverMins);
        add(lblWeekPay);
        add(weeklyPay);




   //Attach event to Button
        btnPay.addActionListener(this);
        btnClear.addActionListener(this);
        btnExit.addActionListener(this);

   }

   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      //Draw any pictures
      //Make sure the picture is in the same directory as the .class files


   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   //This method will fire when button is pressed
   //define temporary variables

   Integer hour = 60;
   Double dblWeeklyPay;
   Integer intLeftOvers;
   Integer inthoursWorked;



   Integer intMinutes = Integer.parseInt(txtMinutes.getText());
   Double dblRate = Double.parseDouble(txtRate.getText());

   inthoursWorked = intMinutes / hour;

   intLeftOvers =  600 - intMinutes;


   dblWeeklyPay = (intMinutes / hour) * dblRate;



hoursWorked.setText(inthoursWorked);
leftoverMins.setText(intLeftOvers);
weeklyPay.setText(dblWeeklyPay);




   }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you learn Swing rather than AWT. Swing components start with "J". Also, the only way to learn layout manager is to play with them. We can't write the code for you because we have no idea what you want the layout to look like. The key to layout managers is that you can use a different one on every panel.

Answer (score 2):

Well when it comes to layouts reading [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) would be a good start. I personally like to use the [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) since it gives you a lot of control, but it can be overkill depending on what you need.

But if you find it too daunting you can always use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) (eclipse is more open source and my favorite) to visually design your GUI.

Comment: +1 for recommending using layout managers and providing a link. -1/2 for recommending code-generation when they're learning GUI coding. :)

Comment: yes I agree. my lazy ways will be my end. You should only use the code-generation tools after you understand the basics. If you don't understand the code... it's all a house of cards

Comment: OK, I'll leave my +1 stand and will withdraw my -1/2! :)